# Can't center image in Header for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with customizing a MikroTik Login Site that I found online.
While everything else worked just fine, I cant get the "images/logo.png" to center on mobile devices. (Devices where the Screen is less wide than the image ~500px)

Yes I know I'm an amateur and I'm in way over my head but I'm sort of pressed on time right now and any help would be greatly appreciated. Putting "center" and "witdh=auto" everywhere and hoping is about all I could do up till now.

If you need anything else please let me know and I will provide it swiftly.

```css
@charset 'UTF-8';
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.1');
  src: url('font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1') format('woff'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1') format('truetype'), url('font/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal
}


/*
 Tessellate 1.0 by HTML5 UP
 html5up.net | @n33co
 Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
*/


/*********************************************************************************/


/* Basic                                                                         */


/*********************************************************************************/

body {
  background: #F8F8F8;
}

body,
input,
textarea,
select {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 17pt;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  color: #888;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #666;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

h1 a,
h2 a,
h3 a,
h4 a,
h5 a,
h6 a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dark h1,
.dark h2,
.dark h3,
.dark h4,
.dark h5,
.dark h6 {
  color: #fff;
}

strong,
b {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: inherit;
}

.dark strong,
.dark b {
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

em,
i {
  font-style: italic;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.dark a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.dark a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

sub {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

sup {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
  margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
}

.dark hr {
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

blockquote {
  border-left: solid 0.25em #e6e6e6;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.dark blockquote {
  border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

p,
ul,
ol,
dl,
table {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

header h1,
header h2,
header h3,
header h4,
header h5,
header h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

header p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.25em 0 0.5em 0;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

br.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.featured {
  text-align: center;
}

.featured p {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Sections/Articles */

section,
article {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}

section> :last-child,
article> :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

section:last-child,
article:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.row>section,
.row>article {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* Images */

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
}

.image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('images/overlay.png');
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.image.featured {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.full {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2em 2em 0;
}

.image.centered {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.centered img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}


/*********************************************************************************/


/* Header                                                                        */


/*********************************************************************************/

#header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background: url('../images/bg-body.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 14em 0 14em 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('images/overlay.png');
}

#header>header,
#header>header p,
#header>footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header header {}

#header header h1 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#header header p {
  margin-top: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#header footer {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}


/*********************************************************************************/


/* Main Sections                                                                 */


/*********************************************************************************/

.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.main>header {
  /*background: #fff; */
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main>header h2 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.main>header p {
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.main>.content {
  padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
}

.main>.content>.container {}

.main>.content h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.main>.content.dark {
  background: #433;
}

.main>.content.style1 {
  background: url('images/bgtr.svg') top right no-repeat, url('images/bgbl.svg') bottom left no-repeat, url('images/bgbl.svg') bottom left no-repeat, url('images/overlay.png'), linear-gradient(45deg, #b39c68, #a56365, #412e4c);
}

.main>.content.style2 {
  background: url('images/bgtr.svg') top right no-repeat, url('images/bgbl.svg') bottom left no-repeat, url('images/overlay.png'), linear-gradient(45deg, #384955, #655361, #85505f);
}

.main>.content.style3 {
  background: url('images/bgtr.svg') top right no-repeat, url('images/bgbl.svg') bottom left no-repeat, url('images/overlay.png'), linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e);
}

.main>.content.style4 {
  padding-top: 0;
  /*background: #fff; */
  background: #000;
}


/*********************************************************************************/


/* Footer                                                                        */


/*********************************************************************************/

#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  padding: 4em 0 8em 0;
}

#footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #aaa;
}

#footer .copyright a {
  color: inherit;
}

#footer ul.icons {}

#footer ul.icons li {}

#footer ul.icons a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hotspot Login</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
  </noscript>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <form name="sendin" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$(link-orig)" />
    <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/md5.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function doLogin() {
      document.sendin.username.value = document.login.username.value;
      document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5('$(chap-id)' + document.login.password.value + '$(chap-challenge)');
      document.sendin.submit();
      return false;
    }
    //-->
  </script>



  <!-- Header -->
  <section id="header" class="dark">
    <header>
      <img src="images/logo.png">
      <h1>Welcome to This Hotspot</h1>
      <!---   <p>Please scroll down to log in</a></p> -->
      <font size="3"><u><a href="#fourth">Press Login</a></u></font>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <a href="#first" class="button scrolly">Guest Login</a>

    </footer>

  </section>
```

Comment: Who writes CSS like this... :D.

Comment: Can you share a demo link so I can look into?

Comment: Hey, i couldn't host it right now but i have uploaded it here: https://www42.zippyshare.com/v/ONEZrYwW/file.html
login.html is the actual one. The others dont really matter.

Comment: @asifsaho Is that helpful?

Comment: Best option is to host somewhere like codepen.io